# Spark 1.5.0 and Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication

Tags: apache-spark, kerberos

I have exception similar to one that Spark 1.3 fixes https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3778
but I faced it with  Spark  version 1.5.0-cdh5.5.2  It happens when submitting spark job to Yarn with kerberos (hadoop.rpc.protection=privacy)

```
16/03/24 19:17:47 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDelegationToken(FSNamesystem.java:7465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getDelegationToken(NameNodeRpcServer.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getDelegationToken(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDelegationToken(FSNamesystem.java:7465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getDelegationToken(NameNodeRpcServer.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getDelegationToken(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:909)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDelegationToken(DFSClient.java:1061)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getDelegationToken(DistributedFileSystem.java:1451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.collectDelegationTokens(FileSystem.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.addDelegationTokens(FileSystem.java:516)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.addDelegationTokens(DistributedFileSystem.java:2137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1914)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:930)
```

Any ideas how it comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception caught was not the root cause of the issue. That's been resolved with substituting absolute file paths with server name and ports on HDFS with just abs path within spark module in

```
saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile

saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://server_name:8020/user/home") --> saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("/user/home")
```